# Restoring all open windows to the monitor they were

Tags: macos, display

Apple is unable to fix macOS in regard to keeping the windows in the monitors they were when the computer restarts, comes from hibernation or, in the case, the second monitor is turned off when this happens.

macOS is even unable to keep the resolution of such monitors.

For the monitor resolution, I found a solution, but not for the windows.

I have an M1 iMac and a UHD TV serving as a second monitor. I have plenty of windows opened on both monitors. Not only that, but I shut down. When the computer starts, all windows are on the iMac monitor.

Is there a way to save their positions and restore them to the original place?

Comment: 'unable to fix'  - would you rather they remained off-screen & inaccessible if it can't find the display? It's a sensible default. The computer doesn't know if that screen is ever going to be connected again. The 'trick' is to manually wake the screen before the Mac, if it's otherwise not fast enough to be recognised in the time it takes the Mac to come back online… or get faster-waking displays. I've had dual screens for 25 years & *almost* never suffer this issue.

Comment: This was working 4 years ago. Since then, it is like the tides, one upgrade fixes it, another destroys it.

Comment: this third party app could solve the issue. it remembers the positions of the windows across restarts or plugging them in and out: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stay/id435410196?mt=12